# How do I pass a variable to the layout using Laravel' Blade templating?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

In Laravel 4, my controller uses a Blade layout:

```php
class PagesController extends BaseController {
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';
}
```

The master layout has outputs the variable title and then displays a view:

```
...
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
...
@yield('content')
....
```

However, in my controller I only appear to be able to pass variables to the subview, not the layout. For example, an action could be:

```php
public function index()
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('pages/index', array('title' => 'Home page'));
}
```

This will only pass the `$title` variable to the content section of the view. How can I provide that variable to the whole view, or at the very least the master layout?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

If you're using `@extends` in your content layout you can use this:

```
@extends('master', ['title' => $title])
```

**Note** that same as above works with children, like:

> ```
> @include('views.subView', ['my_variable' => 'my-value'])
> ```

### Usage

Then where variable is passed to, use it like:

```
<title>{{ $title ?? 'Default Title' }}</title>
```

Comment: It took me a lot of googling to find this! It is just this syntax that you got to get perfect and docs don't show all these subtleties. I mean this is what official docs say `@component('alert', ['foo' => 'bar'])`......

Comment: I am doing this and I am getting an undefined error on the layout page. Any ideas?

Comment: @LucyTurtle see usage section (provide default value, like: `{{ $title ?? 'My Default Title' }}`)

Answer (score 51):

For future Google'rs that use Laravel 5, you can now also use it with includes,

```
@include('views.otherView', ['variable' => 1])
```

Comment: this is what im looking for to finally create a component based application on laravel, thanks!

Comment: if I only pass ["one"], how do I get it in the template?

Answer (score 23):

In the Blade Template : define a variable like this

```
@extends('app',['title' => 'Your Title Goes Here'])
@section('content')
```

And in the app.blade.php or any other of your choice ( I'm just following default Laravel 5 setup )

```
<title>{{ $title or 'Default title Information if not set explicitly' }}</title>
```

This is my first answer here. Hope it works.Good luck!

Comment: This helped me save few hours..! Used it in Laravel 5.4 and it works great.. Thanks for the answer...

Comment: I had to do: `{{ $title ?? 'Default Title' }}`

Answer (score 20):

I was able to solve that problem by adding this to my controller method:

```
    $title = 'My Title Here';
    View::share('title', $title);
```

$this->layout->title = 'Home page'; did not work either.

Comment: This worked for me in laravel 5.1. Easiest way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest way to solve:

```
view()->share('title', 'My Title Here');
```

Or using view Facade:

```
use View;

...

View::share('title', 'My Title Here');
```

Comment: can i execute it in a route middleware?

Answer (score 4):

It appears as though I can pass variables to the entire layout using attributes on the layout object, for example to solve my problem I was able to do the following:

```php
$this->layout->title = 'Home page';
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I currently get an error stating that it does not exist as a variable.

Comment: where can I find the layout object?

Answer (score 1):

```
class PagesController extends BaseController {
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->title = "Home page";
        $this->layout->content = View::make('pages/index');
    }
}
```

At the Blade Template file, REMEMBER to use @ in front the variable.

```
...
<title>{{ $title or '' }}</title>
...
@yield('content')
...
```

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev, this question you should ask back post owner. I just refer back his coding. Kind of weird you ask back me.... And this was answered in 2014. Of course I was referring on the version he asking which is Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1):

just try this simple method:
in controller:-

```
 public function index()
   {
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Home',
            'otherData' => 'Data Here'
        );
        return view('front.landing')->with($data);
   }
```

And in you layout (app.blade.php) :

```
<title>{{ $title }} - {{ config('app.name') }} </title>
```

Thats all.

Comment: Could you explain how this solves the problem? And what new does it contribute over and above the previous (especially accepted) answers?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place an answer, even if it is ok, you should explain it a little bit, and in your case, as there are one similar, try to explain the pros and cons of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the variables of sections you can pay like this:

```php
$_view      = new \View;
$_sections  = $_view->getFacadeRoot()->getSections();
dd($_sections);
/*
Out:
array:1 [▼
  "title" => "Painel"
]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is simple solution worked for me.

```
In layout

    <title>@yield('Page-Title') </title>
```

```
In your blade file 

@section('Page-Title')
My Page Title
@endsection
```

Comment: It works with me on laravel 8 based project, thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('pages/index', array('title' => 'Home page'));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$data['title'] = $this->layout->title = 'The Home Page';
$this->layout->content = View::make('home', $data);
```

I've done this so far because I needed in both the view and master file. It seems if you don't use $this->layout->title it won't be available in the master layout. Improvements welcome!