# How to pass variable to @extends blade

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I have variable {{$template}}.. How can I do for including that variable to @extends. I had try like this:

> @extends({{$template}}) // getting error

I hope, there is one answer to help me. Thanks.

Comment: you mean you want to pass the value for `$template` to your master layout? and from where you are getting the value of `$template`?

Comment: I'm done like this: @extends($template)

Comment: @extends($template) works in laravel 5.2.

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** [How do I pass a variable to the layout using Laravel' Blade templating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118104/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-to-the-layout-using-laravel-blade-templating)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you mean you want to pass the value for `$template` to your layout? and from where you are getting the value of `$template`?

If you want to pass the variable to `layout`, then try doing

```
@extends('<<your layout name>>', ['template' => $template])
```

Comment: So what a child template extends, can be dynamically set. That's handy to know that a child template is not "locked" onto a specific master template that it extends.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
@extends($template)
```

instead of:

```
@extends({{$template}}) // getting error
```