# how send data between child and master blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

how send data between child and master blade ?

```
*master.blade.php*

@if($sidebar == 'true')
<div>...</div>
@endif
```

---

```
*index.blade.php*
@extends('master')
@section('sidebar','true')
```

please help me.
do not use Route and controller and ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118104/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-to-the-layout-using-laravel-blade-templating
I think it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a variable from the child to the parent, the parent must first specify that it expects a variable. This is done using the yield keyword

*master.blade.php*

```html
@if(@yield('hasSidebar') == '1')
<div>...</div>
@endif
```

*index.blade.php*

```
<?php

  @extends('master')

  @section('hasSidebar', '1')
```